# while importing Maven project adding .iml files to SVN source control

Tags: maven, svn, intellij-idea

Hi I am relatively new to Maven and intelliJ IDEA.
While trying to import the Maven project, IDE is asking for adding *.iml files to SVN control.

I wanted to know what does it mean ? and what are the merits and demerits of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iml files are used by intellij to store module specific settings and other information relating to the module. Usually teams do not add `*.iml` files to svn. Typically these files change rapidly, and for no important reason, meaning that if you perform something as simple as a search you'll change the iml file and you'll have a difference with the repo that'll need to be submitted or reverted, and you'll always be in this position. Plus, if a developer does check in the iml, the next developer will have their personal settings overridden whenever they do an update.

Adding files to svn (subversion) is done to maintain a history of a project and to share source files amongst a team. Most teams don't want to share intellij's personal module configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Engineer Dollery, I also wanted to know more about it. Like what does it mean by adding to SVN and what are the benefits of doing so.

Comment: Thanks again @Engineer Dollery for the simple explanation.

Comment: No problems. If you liked the answer, clicking the little tick helps me gain reputation points, which help me gain privileges on SO.